# discord.py bot can't dm multiple users with a role

Tags: discord, discord.py, dm

```
@client.command()
async def eventsoon(ctx):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name='Golden God')
  for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
    if role in member.roles:
      await member.send("ur mom")
```

I want the bot to dm users with golden god role, it doesnt work aand gives no errors

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it's probably happening because you didn't enable **Privileged Gateway intents** and your bot can't get all members. Enable `Server Members Intent` on the Discord Developer site in the **Bot** section.

[image: discord site screenshot]

Then, add them to your code. Example:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```